# How to find the name of current place in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am able to get the latitude and longitude using Geoposition class.How can I find the name of the current location in windows phone 8?

Comment: What makes you think the current place has a name? Or only one? What level of detail are you looking for?

Comment: I am trying to find the current location of the user when my app is launched and I want the city name, latitude and longitude of the location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a built-in API for reverse geocoding in Windows Phone 8. You can do it as follows, for example, to ghet the name of the city:

```cs
string address;
ReverseGeocodeQuery query = new ReverseGeocodeQuery();
query.GeoCoordinate = yourGeoCoordinateObject;
query.QueryCompleted += (s, e) =>
   {
        if (e.Error != null)
            return;

        address = e.Result[0].Information.Address.City;
    };
query.QueryAsync();
```

Comment: "yourGeoCoordinateObject;" what value come in this line. plz explain .

Comment: @Gurunathan an object of type `GeoCoordinate`, which contains latitude and longitude. You can create it for example: `new GeoCoordinate(43.4567, 12.345);`

Answer (score 1):

This is known as Reverse Geocoding. Google offer this as part of their Geocoding API. The specific reference is [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1#ReverseGeocoding)

You can make a call to their API with a simple HTTP request:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true
```

And they'll return a list of human-readable names in JSON format.